# Construct sequence in $R^{2}$ such that for every point in the sequence that is on the unit circle, $\exists$ subsequence that converges to the point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I solve the following problem?

Construct a sequence $\left\{z_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the property that for any point $z = (x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2 = 1$ there exists a subsequence $\left\{z_{k_{n}}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $z_{k_{n}}\rightarrow z$.

Comment: consider $(\cos n,\sin n)$

Comment: @Glare yes, I fixed it thank you

Comment: $(\cos n,\sin n)$ works by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem , but that is quite an overkill. You may prove through the pigeonhole principle that if $\alpha$ is an irrational number, the sequence given by the fractional part of $\alpha n$ is dense in $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to consider an enumeration $q_1,q_2,q_3,\ldots$ of the points with rational coordinates inside $[-1,1]^2$. That is a countable dense subset of the square and the unit circle is a subset of such a square, hence for every point $Q$ on the circle and every $n\geq 1$ we may pick some $q_{k(n)}$ (with $k(n)>k(n-1)$) that belongs to the ball centered at $Q$ with radius $\frac{1}{2^n}$, enforcing $\lim_{n\to +\infty}q_{k(n)}=Q$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(\cos n,\sin n)$ that @Chilango provided will work, but it might get a touch difficult for you to prove.

The problem amounts to constructing a countable dense subset $A\subset S^1$, since then every point of $S^1$ will be a limit point of $A$, and hence have some subsequence convergent to it.

Here's a sequence which should be slightly easier to verify: pick an enumeration $\{r_k\}$ of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. Note that any point on $S^1$ can be written as $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for unique $\theta$ modulo $2\pi$. In particular, given $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, there is some subsequence of the $\{r_k\}$ such that $r_{k_n}\to \theta$ by density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. It should be easy for you to check from here that $z_k = (\cos r_k, \sin r_k)$ satisfies the properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can even arrange matters so that the points of the unit circle are the *only* points in the plane that are limits of subsequences of your sequence. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$ let $u_{n,k}$ be the point whose polar coordinates are

$$\left\langle 1-\frac1n,\frac{2\pi k}n\right\rangle\;,$$

and take as your sequence

$$\langle u_{1,0},u_{2,0},u_{2,1},u_{3,0},u_{3,1},u_{3,2},u_{4,0},\ldots\rangle\;.$$

The sequence starts at the origin, then has two diametrically opposite points on the circle of radius $\frac12$ centred at the origin, then three equally spaced points on the circle of radius $\frac23$ centred at the origin, four equally spaced points on the circle of radius $\frac34$ centred at the origin, and so on.